Firebase Push Notifications Not Working in .NET MAUI 8 on Physical Android Devices
I'm having problems with Firebase push notifications in my .NET MAUI 8 Android project. While debugging on emulators goes smoothly, everything works fine, the real headache starts when I switch to debugging on physical devices. Despite having all the necessary Firebase push notification plugins in place, push notifications simply refuse to show up.
If anyone has tips or insights on how to manage this issue and get push notifications working seamlessly on real devices during debugging sessions, I'd greatly appreciate your advice!
Plugins being used (Everything updated)
Android MainActivity
Firebase Service
AndroidManifest
google-services.json file is located In {ProjectName}/Platforms/Android/google-services.json and set the Build Action to GoogleServicesJson.
Note: this is only an Android project
I've double-checked permissions, configurations, and even tried different physical devices, but no luck so far.

What does not working mean? Was the methoed about notification received fired?
